# Looking for a simple way to validate a form via js.

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

**Hey guys new to javascript (maybe a month in) and i am running into a bump. i'd like to create a validation form via js. Not sure where i can start. I thought about disabling the submit button until all forms are filled out but not sure how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. **

```css
body {
  background: #384047;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

form {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3em 2em 2em;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #222;
  border-radius: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  position: relative;
}

#moreInfo {
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Drop-down menu's */

#dropDown1 {
  width: 350px;
  color: grey;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

#dropDown2 {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  color: grey;
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  color: #333;
}

input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
}

#firstName {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#lastName {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#eMail {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#telephone {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#address {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* buttons */

#submitMore {
  background: #2080df;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #68b25b;
}

#applyNow {
  background: #40bf80;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 2em 0 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #68b25b;
}

#para1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: #dadada;
  padding: ;
}

#OReo {
  text-align: center;
  color: #dadada;
  font-size: 1em;
}



/*      Validation Form Response      */

input[type="text"],
input[type="firstName"] {
 background: #f5f5f5;
 border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 padding: .8em .5em;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="#" method="post">

    <!-- drop-down -->
    <h1 id="moreInfo">Request More Information</h1>

    <p>
      <label for="degreeType">What Degree would you like?*</label>
      <select id="dropDown1" name="dropDown1">
    <option id="dropDown1" selected="selected">Select an option</option>
    <option value="gen2">Example 1</option>
    <option value="gen3">Example 2</option>
    <option value="gen4">Example 3</option>
  </select>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="selectDegree">What would you like to study?*<label>
      <select id="dropDown2" name="dropDown2">
    <option selected="selected">Select degree type above</option>
    <option value="gen2">Example 1</option>
    <option value="gen3">Example 2</option>
    <option value="gen4">Example 3</option>
</select>
  </p>
        <div class="firstNlast">
        <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name*<label>
        <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="firstName">
          <span class="left">Please enter your name</span>
        </p>
          
          <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name*<label>
        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="lastName">
          <span class="right">Please enter your last name</span>
        </p>
            </div>
          
          <p>
        <label for="eMail">Email*<label>
        <input id="eMail" name="eMail" type="text">
          <span class="left">Please enter your email</span>
        </p>
         
          <p>
        <label for="telephone">Telephone*<label>
        <input id="telephone" name="telephone" type="text">
          <span class="right">Please enter your phone number</span>
        </p>
         
          <p>
        <label for="address">Address*<label>
        <input id="address" name="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
        <span class="left">Please enter your address</span>
        </p>
        
         <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Tell Me More" id="submitMore">
          </p>
          <p id="para1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices pulvinar scelerisque. Curabitur auctor faucibus est, ut lobortis ante tempus sit amet. Phasellus fermentum aliquet turpis, at tempus tortor euismod nec. Pellentesque ligula nunc, maximus et venenatis ac, tempor vel sem.
       </p>
          <h1 id="OReo">----------  OR  -------------</h1>
          <input type="submit" value="Apply Now" id="applyNow">
```

Comment: if you want to make sure a field should be filled. Add `required` attribute on it

Comment: thanks! I am looking for a solution specifically for js. :)

Comment: This feels like yoou'd benefit from a tutorial, and SO is a terrible tutorial.

Comment: Disabling submit button sucks [[1](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/73728/should-form-continue-button-be-disabled-if-validation-is-incomplete)] [[2](https://axesslab.com/disabled-buttons-suck/)] and it will not help you and others if use [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) plz think no-js solution first and foremost. You have room for improvement on your input by specifying more (correct) attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
function onInput() {
  //Get input value
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("field1").value;
  //See if the input value is empty or not
  if (inputValue.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("field2").setAttribute("disabled", false);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('field2').disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Add a listener with:

```
<input type="text" id="field1" oninput="onInput()">
```

If you're using Jquery:

```
<input type="text" id="field1">
```

And your script here (same logic):

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#field1', function(){
  var inputValue = $('#field1').val();
  if (inputValue.length > 0) $('#field2').prop('disabled', true);
  else $('#field2').prop('disabled', false);
})
```

I haven't tested this code but it should work as intended.

Comment: ok, please disregard the title. That is wildly incorrect and I am very sorry. I am trying to validate my form via js. That's it.

Comment: If you're trying to make sure that all required fields are filled, the HTML required attribute should do the trick. I believe even iOS Safari checks for empty required fields before submitting the form.

Comment: And if you're trying to do some specific operations when validating your form, you can loop through your input fields using:

var form = document.querySelector('form'); //where form is the id of your HTML form
var inputs = form.elements;

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
    // do stuff with inputs[i]
}

Answer (score 0):

This is just a matter of setting the second input to be `disabled` by default and then removing that attribute (or re-setting it) whenever the first input gets any input.

```js
// Get references to the two inputs
var firstInput = document.getElementById("firstName");
var secondInput = document.getElementById("lastName");

// Set up an event handler for the frist input for when it gets content
firstInput.addEventListener("input", function(){

  // Remove or set the disabled attribute based on the value of the fist input
  if(this.value !== ""){
    secondInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    secondInput.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #384047;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

form {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3em 2em 2em;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #222;
  border-radius: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  position: relative;
}

#moreInfo {
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Drop-down menu's */

#dropDown1 {
  width: 350px;
  color: grey;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

#dropDown2 {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  color: grey;
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  color: #333;
}

input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
}

#firstName {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#lastName {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#eMail {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#telephone {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#address {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* buttons */

#submitMore {
  background: #2080df;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #68b25b;
}

#applyNow {
  background: #40bf80;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 2em 0 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #68b25b;
}

#para1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: #dadada;
  padding: ;
}

#OReo {
  text-align: center;
  color: #dadada;
  font-size: 1em;
}



/*      Validation Form Response      */

input[type="text"],
input[type="firstName"] {
 background: #f5f5f5;
 border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 padding: .8em .5em;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="#" method="post">

    <!-- drop-down -->
    <h1 id="moreInfo">Request More Information</h1>

    <p>
      <label for="degreeType">What Degree would you like?*</label>
      <select id="dropDown1" name="dropDown1">
    <option id="dropDown1" selected="selected">Select an option</option>
    <option value="gen2">Example 1</option>
    <option value="gen3">Example 2</option>
    <option value="gen4">Example 3</option>
  </select>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="selectDegree">What would you like to study?*<label>
      <select id="dropDown2" name="dropDown2">
    <option selected="selected">Select degree type above</option>
    <option value="gen2">Example 1</option>
    <option value="gen3">Example 2</option>
    <option value="gen4">Example 3</option>
</select>
  </p>
        <div class="firstNlast">
        <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name*<label>
        <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="firstName">
          <span class="left">Please enter your name</span>
        </p>
          
          <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name*<label>
        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="lastName" disabled> <!-- Disabled by default -->
          <span class="right">Please enter your last name</span>
        </p>
            </div>
          
          <p>
        <label for="eMail">Email*<label>
        <input id="eMail" name="eMail" type="text">
          <span class="left">Please enter your email</span>
        </p>
         
          <p>
        <label for="telephone">Telephone*<label>
        <input id="telephone" name="telephone" type="text">
          <span class="right">Please enter your phone number</span>
        </p>
         
          <p>
        <label for="address">Address*<label>
        <input id="address" name="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
        <span class="left">Please enter your address</span>
        </p>
        
         <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Tell Me More" id="submitMore">
          </p>
          <p id="para1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices pulvinar scelerisque. Curabitur auctor faucibus est, ut lobortis ante tempus sit amet. Phasellus fermentum aliquet turpis, at tempus tortor euismod nec. Pellentesque ligula nunc, maximus et venenatis ac, tempor vel sem.
       </p>
          <h1 id="OReo">----------  OR  -------------</h1>
          <input type="submit" value="Apply Now" id="applyNow">
```